# Fragment with ViewPager issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to create soemthing like this:

[image]

The ViewPager is attached to an adapter which has 2 fragments. One to list the upcoming orders and the other to list the past orders.

So the image shown above has a main fragment which hosts the ViewPager, and the adapter creates 2 fragments as children of the main fragment.

For sake of simplicity I'll call the main fragment as "**Parent fragment**" and the two fragments supplied by the adapter as "**children fragments**".

Once the parent fragment is created or resumed it has to fetch a list of data from the server and pass it to the two children fragment(The children fragments will process the list of data and display the necessary data). Both the children fragments have a listView, and each listView row item is clickable.

Now, the data fetched by the parent fragment has to be passed to the children fragments before the ViewPager is attached to the adapter. So I do not attach the adapter to the ViewPager in the onCreate method of the parent fragment, but rather once the list of data is fetched, I attach the adapter to the ViewPager in the onPostExecute method of the async task after the data is fetched.

This works fine the first time, but once I click on a listView row item of the child fragment and then press the back button, the getItem() method of the adapter is not called, but the onResume methods of the children fragments are called even before the data is fetched from the server.

So I guess the android framework remembers that the children fragment have already been created, and does not recreate them again.

**How do I ensure that the children fragments are created/called only after the data is fetched from the server in the parent fragment?**

I am adding some code for clarity.

**BookingHistory.java(Parent Fragment)**

```
    public class BookingHistory extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ViewPager mPager;
    SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
    Toolbar toolBar;
    View view;

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private OrderTask mOrderTask = null;
    UserFunctions userFunctions = null;
    OrderFunctions orderFunctions = null;
    private BookingHistoryListener mListener;
    private List<Order> mOrderList;

    PlacedOrders upcomingOrders;
    PlacedOrders pastOrders;

    public BookingHistory() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mOrderList = null;
        mPager = null;
        mTabs = null;
        upcomingOrders = null;
        pastOrders = null;
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        fetchOrders();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking_history, container, false);
        toolBar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_s);
        if (toolBar != null) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
            toolBar.setTitle("");
            tv.setText("History");
        }
        return view;
    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String tabs[] = {"Upcoming", "Past"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                upcomingOrders = PlacedOrders.newInstance(Constants.DATE_TODAY_FUTURE);
                upcomingOrders.getOrderList(mOrderList);
                return upcomingOrders;
            } else {
                pastOrders = PlacedOrders.newInstance(Constants.DATE_PAST);
                pastOrders.getOrderList(mOrderList);
                return pastOrders;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public void fetchOrders() {
        if (mOrderTask != null) {
            return;
        }
        progress.show();
        mOrderTask = new OrderTask(getActivity());
        mOrderTask.execute((Void) null);
    }

    public class OrderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final Activity mActivity;

        OrderTask(Activity activity) {
            mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            orderFunctions = new OrderFunctions();
            return orderFunctions.getList(userFunctions.getToken(mActivity));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mOrderTask = null;
            progress.dismiss();
            if (success) {
                mOrderList = UserProfile.getOrders();
                //attaching the view pager to adapter here!
                mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
                mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
                mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                    @Override
                    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
                    }
                });
                mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
                mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
            } else {
                //Error handling stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PlacedOrders.java(Children Fragments)**

```
    public class PlacedOrders extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private static String flag;
    private int dateFlag;
    private PlacedOrdersListener mListener;
    UserFunctions userFunctions = null;
    OrderFunctions orderFunctions = null;
    private PlacedOrdersAdapter ordersAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private List<Order> mOrderList;
    private List<Order> mPendingOrderList;
    private List<Order> mCompletedOrderList;

    public static PlacedOrders newInstance(int date) {
        PlacedOrders fragment = new PlacedOrders();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(flag, date);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void getOrderList(List<Order> orderList) {
        this.mOrderList = orderList;
    }

    public PlacedOrders() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            dateFlag = getArguments().getInt(flag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mPendingOrderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
        mCompletedOrderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placed_orders, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        displayOrders();
    }

    private void displayOrders() {
        if (isVisible() && (mOrderList != null)) {
            mPendingOrderList.clear();
            mCompletedOrderList.clear();
            ListView listViewOrder = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.orderList);
            if(dateFlag == Constants.DATE_TODAY_FUTURE) {
                for(int i = 0; i < mOrderList.size(); i++) {
                    String status = mOrderList.get(i).status;
                    if(status.equals("PENDING") || status.equals("PROCESSING")) {
                        mPendingOrderList.add(mOrderList.get(i));
                        ordersAdapter = new PlacedOrdersAdapter(mPendingOrderList, getActivity().getLayoutInflater());
                        listViewOrder.setAdapter(ordersAdapter);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(dateFlag == Constants.DATE_PAST) {
                for(int i = 0; i < mOrderList.size(); i++) {
                    String status = mOrderList.get(i).status;
                    if(status.equals("COMPLETE")) {
                        mCompletedOrderList.add(mOrderList.get(i));
                        ordersAdapter = new PlacedOrdersAdapter(mCompletedOrderList, getActivity().getLayoutInflater());
                        listViewOrder.setAdapter(ordersAdapter);
                    }
                }
            }

            listViewOrder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               //Display a new fragment on clicking
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should do the fragment transaction of container fragment, **Parent fragment**, in activity only after data is fetched and if it is fetching show progress bar or something?

Comment: Yeah that should work, but can it not be done the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and this was my solution :
In container fragment (fragment that contains tabs) in `onViewCreated()` method I created `startFetch()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.home_tab_pager);
        mTabsHost= (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appTabs);
        startFetch();
    }
```

Then in `startFetch` method i use Volley request and in `onResponse` method i update data and then add tabs :

```
public void startFetch(){
        //Create volley request
        String url = BuildConfig.API_GET_CATEGORIES;
        final RequestQueue queue = VolleyService.getInstance(this.getContext()).getRequestQueue();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // we got the response, now our job is to handle it
                try {
                    updateCategoryData(response);
                } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //something happened, treat the error.
                Log.e("ErrorFETCH", error.networkResponse.toString());
            }
        });

        queue.add(request);
    }
```

My `udpateCategory()` method :

```
public void updateCategoryData(final String stream) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {
//Update the data to SQLITE
setupTabs();
}
```

My `setupTabs()` method :

```
public void setUpTabs(){
        ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                Category.Entry.CONTENT_URI, // URI
                Category.PROJECTION,                // Projection
                Category.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_PARENT_ID + " = ?",   // Selection
                new String[]{"0"},                          // Selection args
                null);

        if (data != null) {
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                categories.add(new Category(data));
            }
        }

        TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), this.getActivity(), categories);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        mTabsHost.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
```

Comment: I guess both you and I are doing the same thing here, except that you are using Volley whereas I am using an AsyncTask!